extracting data from a callback sent by a post request
when the balance of my service is updated, then to my server http://.../callback a post request comes with data from the screenshot and from this data I need to extract _id and socialnetworkId into a variable for further addition to the bot database and interaction (data.from.socialNetworkId and
data.from._id )
request data
I tried to run this code and output a variable on the site to check, but I get an error code of 500 and I'm not sure if the server was able to process the data
...
# Getting data from an incoming request
data = request.json

try:
        # Extracting the necessary parameters
        social_network_id = data['from']['socialNetworkId']
        user_id = data['from']['_id']
...
@app.route('/print')
def print():
    return (f"Social Network ID: {social_network_id}")


